# Swift firestore get more than one collection's documents at same time?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to get more than one collection's documents data?

my firebase tree is like :
 "tahminler/'useruid'/'date as like (5.3.2018 or 6.3.2018)'/'documentID'/'Document data'"

so how to take all dates collection's documents in a function 
and here is my firebase firestore console:  [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firestore doesn't have a way to make a single query across multiple collecitons.  You will have to query each collection individually, then merge the results in your client code.

If it's important to be able to make a single query for everything you need, considering restructuring or duplicating your data to suit that query.